# How to get php/ajax to get an integer from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

The application is made to keep a track of how many cables are in stock.

So the part of my application that I am struggling to get working is the following.

When a user selects something from the dropdown box, it queries the MySQL database and returns an integer. There is only 1 integer per selection. For example a user selects a 5 metre orange cable from the drop down box it will display the amount of cables left. Which is stored in the mysql database. I am having a nightmare getting the code to work if someone could please provide some assistance.

Here is the main page

```
    <html>
<head>
  <title>Cable Management</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>





<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<?php include("Header.php"); ?>
  <div id="main">
        <h1>Cable Management</h1>
        <h2>Bournemouth Office</h2>
        <p>Enter how many cables you want to remove or add from the Bournemouth office</p>
        <script>
function showcables(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getcable.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" NAME='amount' VALUE ="">
<select name="cables" onchange="showcables(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a cable type</option>
<option value="0.25 Metre Orange">0.25 Metre Orange</option>
<option value="0.3 Metre Orange">0.3 Metre Orange</option>
<option value="0.5 Metre Orange">0.5 Metre Orange</option>
<option value="1 Metre Orange">1 Metre Orange</option>
<option value="2 Metre Orange">2 Metre Orange</option>
<option value="3 Metre Orange">3 Metre Orange</option>
<option value="5 Metre Orange">5 Metre Orange</option>
<option value="10 Metre Orange">10 Metre Orange</option>
<option value="2 Metre Black">2 Metre Black</option>
<option value="3 Metre Black">3 Metre Black</option>
<option value="5 Metre Black">5 Metre Black</option>
<option value="10 Metre Black">10 Metre Black</option>
<option value="RJ 11">RJ11</option>
<option value="RJ 11 to BT">RJ11 to BT</option>
</select>
<INPUT TYPE = "button" Name = "Remove" VALUE = "Remove">
<INPUT TYPE = "button" Name = "Add" VALUE = "Add">
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>The amount of cables of that type will be listed here</b></div>

        </select>



    </div>
    <div class="footer-clear"></div><!-- add this at the end of wrapper -->
</div> <!-- i added this closing tag, it was missing (for wrapper) -->
<?php include("Footer.php"); ?> <!-- move footer to go outside of wrapper -->
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the getcable.php file

```
    <?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','cables');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"bmouthoff");
$sql="SELECT * FROM bmouthoff WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Amount'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should think about using jQuery instead of native XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @Lame-up-duck you should think about learning JavaScript, instead of using jQuery for the most mundane things.

Comment: and setup a test case somewhere and explain the exact issue you're trying to solve, I'm not sure if anyone is going to rewrite your code for you.

Comment: You're missing the opening `<table>` tag. Other than that, I don't see a problem. But I wonder why you're using a table if there's only one row per selection.

Comment: @tereško: you'r right, but IMHO using XMLHttpRequest is a pain.

Comment: @Lame-up-duck then write a wrapper ... that takes about 20 lines of (reusable) code. Instead of slapping on almost 100KB of boilerplate

Comment: @tereško: you'r right again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put:

```
echo "<table>";
```

before:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

in the PHP.

Get rid of `mysqli_select_db($con, "bmouthoff")`. That's not the name of the database, and you already selected the database in the `mysqli_connect()` call.

```
die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_error($con));
```

should be:

```
die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
```

And change:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

to:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ("Could not query: " . mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Thanks,

Still doesn't seem to be working. Just to verify my database is called cables and the table I want to use is bmouthoff. It's been a while since i've touched programming so pleas bare with me

Comment: I've added some other corrections, although I don't think they're related to your problem.

Comment: Great thanks, looks like its doing something now. But I am getting a visual error. Could not query: Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'
I assume thats a problem with mysql?